# What is a staff week?

Tags: scheduling, terminology

I have heard the term "staff" week. I know that calendar week is the actual calendar days but what is a "staff" week?

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

The only way to know for sure is to ask someone at your company what the term means *at your company* or within a given project-related context. Even if there were a standard definition, that doesn't ensure that's how it's being used within *your* project.

### Guesses and Practical Advice

I don't know if there's a widely-accepted definition, and it's not one I've ever hear used professionally. Depending on company culture, I would guess that it's either:

1. The total hours of all staff on the project for a week (either a calendar week or a work week).

   - This might be used as a number used for estimating team capacity.
   - Alternatively, it could be the average run-rate for labor within a given project.
   - On the *other* other hand, it could also mean something no one outside your company or project would guess.
2. As David suggested (and I'm paraphrasing), it could simply be a poor attempt at replacing the industrial-age term "resource" with "staff member."

   - Some companies are currently attempting to attract and keep people by treating them less as fungible resources. Whether or not this is *sincere* is largely irrelevant to the goal.
   - Some companies still have red/blue badge syndrome. This could be an attempt to differentiate between staff labor and contractor/vendor labor.
   - It might mean the estimated capacity of an individual or group of people based on expected or contractual labor agreements, such as 40- or 60-hour work weeks being standard for that company or project.

#### Ask, Don't Guess!

In any case, the real solution is not to guess. Since every company has its own culture and set of self-generated acronyms and shorthand, just *ask* someone. The next time someone uses that term, asking:

> Can you please clarify what "staff week" means in this context?

would be perfectly appropriate. Some people don't realize how non-standard their company's terms are, and not every company or project defines a glossary (although many should). Don't be afraid to ask questions at work, because it's the only way to find out what a term means *at your company* rather than from random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Curious - what does "red/blue badge syndrome" means? Couldn't find any reference to it (I'm not too desperate to search page 2 of Google results :P)

Comment: @TiagoCardoso Some companies use different colored badges to differentiate between "employees" and "contractors." From an organizational culture perspective, it's a problem where employees and contractors are treated differently or given different levels of access even when doing the exact same job. The actual colors used are irrelevant; it's a mindset and a culture.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a new term for resource week since "resource" is no longer the right term to describe an employee. It should mean a planning parametric to load employees against a task. For example, some firms would use 38 hours a week per staff so that you can compute duration and costs.